# Issues with multicols when using a template

Tags: two-column, multicolumn

I am using this template to write a paper. My paper starts with two column format but in the middle I need to show a big table. Hence, I have to switch to one column.

I am trying to use the multicol package. However, the \twocolumn formatting is already define in the template available at http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.cls. I tried to remove just the section containing \twocolumn in the template. However, it doesn't work. My author, paper title don't show up if I remove the \twocolumn text in the template.

I am just  trying to use \begin{multicols}{2} in the paper. How can I fix this ?

Any suggestions guys. This template is making me handicapped.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use a journal specific class and then radically change the formatting (eg by introducing multicol instead of the built in twocolumn) if it is for a paper submission you need to follow the journal guidelines, and if it is not, then use a generic class such as article

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. I need to change the twocolumn to one column for a certain section. However, if I use like \onecolumn then it will create a new page leaving void spaces. How can I remedy it?

Comment: why can yo not use the standard table* environment for a full width table?